# $\frac {1+a}{1-a} + \frac{1+b}{1-b} +\frac{1+c}{1-c}\leq \frac{2a}{b}+\frac{2b}{c} +\frac{2c}{a}.$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ s.t. $a+b+c=1$.

Show that $\frac {1+a}{1-a} + \frac{1+b}{1-b} +\frac{1+c}{1-c}\leq \frac{2a}{b}+\frac{2b}{c} +\frac{2c}{a}.$

My idea: I have to show that

3+ $\frac{2a}{1-a}+\frac{2b}{1-b}+\frac{2c}{1-c}\leq \frac{2a}{b}+\frac{2b}{c} +\frac{2c}{a}$ which is equivalent with $ \frac{3}{2}+ \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\leq \frac{2a}{b}+\frac{2b}{c} +\frac{2c}{a}.$

I used Nesbitt' s inequality and it's enough to show that $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\leq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{a}.$

I notice that $\frac{4a}{b+c}\leq \frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{c}$.
Now I am stuck.

Comment: Various solutions on AoPS: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%20%7B1%2Ba%7D%7B1-a%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%2Bb%7D%7B1-b%7D%20%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%2Bc%7D%7B1-c%7D%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7B2a%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2b%7D%7Bc%7D%20%2B%5Cfrac%7B2c%7D%7Ba%7D.%24

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proving $\frac{1+a}{1-a}+\frac{1+b}{1-b}+\frac{1+c}{1-c}\leq 2(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{c})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777956/proving-frac1a1-a-frac1b1-b-frac1c1-c-leq-2-fracba-frac) Found using [a more precise query on approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%20%7B1%2Ba%7D%7B1-a%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%2Bb%7D%7B1-b%7D%20%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%2Bc%7D%7B1-c%7D%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7B2a%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2b%7D%7Bc%7D%20%2B%5Cfrac%7B2c%7D%7Ba%7D%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&p=2)